# How to update a class with a record member using the Singleton Pattern in F#

Tags: f#, singleton

Lets say I have this record definition:

```
type WindowServices =
    {
        ReportMenu: Window option 
        ProgressNotes: Window option
        PatientRegistration: Window option
    }
```

Furthermore, I have this class in which I am attempting to implement the Singleton pattern:

```
type WindowServiceManager private(wss) =  
    let mutable ws:WindowServices = wss  
    member this.WS 
        with get () = ws
        and set (value) = ws <- value
    
    static member val Instance = 
            let wss = {ReportMenu = None; ProgressNotes = None; PatientRegistration = None}    
            WindowServiceManager(wss)
```

Outside of the class, the singleton "Instance" seems to correctly be obtained with:

```
let i = WindowServiceManager.Instance
```

However, absolutely *nothing* I have tried can change the default record values. That is, this fails. The new values in "windowServices" are never entered into WS:

```
let windowServices : WindowServices = 
              { ReportMenu = Some  reportMenu; 
                ProgressNotes = Some progressNoteWindow; 
                PatientRegistration = Some patientRegistrationWindow }
           
i.WS <- windowServices
```

How is this done?

TIA

Addendum: The following shows failure. "failwith" is *ALWAYS* hit:

```
let getReportMenuService : Window = 
    let i = WindowServiceManager.Instance
    let p = match i.WS.ReportMenu with
        | None -> failwith "[ReportMenuService] Something went wrong!"
        | Some s -> s
    p
```

Comment: How do you know that it fails?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that getReportMenuService, being a value rather than a function, is evaluated even before your program starts running for real. At that time the value of ReportMenu is still None. The snippets you've posted doesn't tell the real story. Just turn getReportMenuService into a function by adding a parenthesis after the name, and call it likewise. See if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's something going on elsewhere in your code that you haven't yet shared with us. The code you've provided works as expected (using `Window` as an alias for `string` for simplicity):

```ml
type Window = string

type WindowServices =
    {
        ReportMenu: Window option 
        ProgressNotes: Window option
        PatientRegistration: Window option
    }

type WindowServiceManager private(wss) =  
    let mutable ws:WindowServices = wss  
    member this.WS 
        with get () = ws
        and set (value) = ws <- value
    
    static member val Instance = 
            let wss = {ReportMenu = None; ProgressNotes = None; PatientRegistration = None}    
            WindowServiceManager(wss)

let i = WindowServiceManager.Instance

let windowServices : WindowServices = 
              { ReportMenu = Some "ReportMenu";
                ProgressNotes = Some "ProgressNotes" ;
                PatientRegistration = Some "PatientRegistration" }
           
i.WS <- windowServices

let getReportMenuService : Window = 
    let i = WindowServiceManager.Instance
    let p =
        match i.WS.ReportMenu with
        | None -> failwith "[ReportMenuService] Something went wrong!"
        | Some s -> s
    p

getReportMenuService
    |> printfn "%A"   // "ReportMenu"
```

Comment: Could you try it with an actual System.Windows.Window? I’m away from my project at the moment. The window definitions came from Wpf/xaml.  Thanks.

Comment: The Windows come from C# Func <Window> Where each window Func has the form ()=> ReportMenu() followed by Invoke().  Thanks.